# Add Puerto Rico to JQV Map (Countries)

Tags: jquery, svg, jqvmap

Using the JQVMaps plugin with the World Map (by Countries) data, and need to be able to select Puerto Rico individually (right now it is bunched in with the US). Have been trying to look through the US' path points, but cannot make sense of them. Does someone have path points for it, or could advise on how the paths are formed? I know the Python creator exists, but I'm hoping to just be able to take out the path points from the US' data and create a new Puerto Rico object.

Comment: I use [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) to edit and create thous paths and then be hable to use them as objects to be call by id. their web page got various tutorials that could help you achieve your goal and is a great __GNU__ ([GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html)) tool to have under your belt. Give it a shot, you won't regret it.

Comment: Thank you! Definitely want to check out Inkscape. I was in a time crunch and found [Polynom.co](http://polynom.co)-- was able to paste in the US path points and remove paths until I tracked down Puerto Rico. Will post findings and dive into Inkscape!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out-- found [Polynom.co](http://polynom.co) and was able to paste in the US path points and remove paths until I was left with Puerto Rico.

For anyone else looking to make US and Puerto Rico individually selectable, the "us" object in jquery.vmap.world.js:

```
"us":{"path":"M69.17,53.35l3.46,6.47l2.22-0.5v-2.24L69.17,53.35L69.17,53.35M49.66,110.26l-0.17,3.01l2.16-0.5v-1.34L49.66,110.26L49.66,110.26M46.34,111.6l-4.32,2.18l0.67,2.34l1.66-1.34l3.32-1.51L46.34,111.6L46.34,111.6M28.39,114.44l-2.99-0.67l-0.5,1.34l0.33,2.51L28.39,114.44L28.39,114.44M22.07,114.28l-2.83-1.17l-1,1.84l1.83,1.84L22.07,114.28L22.07,114.28M12.27,111.6l-1.33-1.84l-1.33,0.5v2.51l1.5,1L12.27,111.6L12.27,111.6M1.47,99.71l1.66,1.17l-0.5,1.34H1.47V99.71L1.47,99.71M10,248.7l-0.14,2.33l2.04,1.37l1.22-1.09L10,248.7L10,248.7M15.29,252.13l-1.9,1.37l1.63,2.05l1.9-1.64L15.29,252.13L15.29,252.13M19.1,255.41l-1.63,2.19l0.54,1.37l2.31-1.09L19.1,255.41L19.1,255.41M21.81,259.65l-0.95,5.47l0.95,2.05l3.12-0.96l1.63-2.74l-3.4-3.15L21.81,259.65L21.81,259.65M271.05,281.06l-2.64-0.89l-2.12,1.33l1.06,1.24l3.61,0.53L271.05,281.06L271.05,281.06M93.11,44.89l-8.39,1.99l1.73,9.45l9.13,2.49l0.49,1.99L82.5,65.04l-7.65,12.68l2.71,13.43L82,94.13l3.46-3.23l0.99,1.99l-4.2,4.97l-16.29,7.46l-10.37,2.49l-0.25,3.73l23.94-6.96l9.87-2.74l9.13-11.19l10.12-6.71l-5.18,8.7l5.68,0.75l9.63-4.23l1.73,6.96l6.66,1.49l6.91,6.71l0.49,4.97l-0.99,1.24l1.23,4.72h1.73l0.25-7.96h1.97l0.49,19.64l4.94-4.23l-3.46-20.39h-5.18l-5.68-7.21l27.89-47.25l-27.64-21.63l-30.85,5.97l-1.23,9.45l6.66,3.98l-2.47,6.47L93.11,44.89L93.11,44.89M148.76,158.34l-1,4.02l-3.49-2.26h-1.74l-1,4.27l-12.21,27.36l3.24,23.84l3.99,2.01l0.75,6.53h8.22l7.97,6.02l15.69,1.51l1.74,8.03l2.49,1.76l3.49-3.51l2.74,1.25l2.49,11.54l4.23,2.76l3.49-6.53l10.71-7.78l6.97,3.26l5.98,0.5l0.25-3.76l12.45,0.25l2.49,2.76l0.5,6.27l-1.49,3.51l1.74,6.02h3.74l3.74-5.77l-1.49-2.76l-1.49-6.02l2.24-6.78l10.21-8.78l7.72-2.26l-1-7.28l10.71-11.55l10.71-1.76L272.8,199l10.46-6.02v-8.03l-1-0.5l-3.74,1.25l-0.5,4.92l-12.43,0.15l-9.74,6.47l-15.29,5l-2.44-2.99l6.94-10.5l-3.43-3.27l-2.33-4.44l-4.83-3.88l-5.25-0.44l-9.92-6.77L148.76,158.34L148.76,158.34z","name":"United States of America"},
```

should be replaced with:

```
"us":{"path":"M69.17,53.35l3.46,6.47l2.22-0.5v-2.24L69.17,53.35L69.17,53.35M49.66,110.26l-0.17,3.01l2.16-0.5v-1.34L49.66,110.26L49.66,110.26M46.34,111.6l-4.32,2.18l0.67,2.34l1.66-1.34l3.32-1.51L46.34,111.6L46.34,111.6M28.39,114.44l-2.99-0.67l-0.5,1.34l0.33,2.51L28.39,114.44L28.39,114.44M22.07,114.28l-2.83-1.17l-1,1.84l1.83,1.84L22.07,114.28L22.07,114.28M12.27,111.6l-1.33-1.84l-1.33,0.5v2.51l1.5,1L12.27,111.6L12.27,111.6M1.47,99.71l1.66,1.17l-0.5,1.34H1.47V99.71L1.47,99.71M10,248.7l-0.14,2.33l2.04,1.37l1.22-1.09L10,248.7L10,248.7M15.29,252.13l-1.9,1.37l1.63,2.05l1.9-1.64L15.29,252.13L15.29,252.13M19.1,255.41l-1.63,2.19l0.54,1.37l2.31-1.09L19.1,255.41L19.1,255.41M21.81,259.65l-0.95,5.47l0.95,2.05l3.12-0.96l1.63-2.74l-3.4-3.15L21.81,259.65L21.81,259.65M93.11,44.89l-8.39,1.99l1.73,9.45l9.13,2.49l0.49,1.99L82.5,65.04l-7.65,12.68l2.71,13.43L82,94.13l3.46-3.23l0.99,1.99l-4.2,4.97l-16.29,7.46l-10.37,2.49l-0.25,3.73l23.94-6.96l9.87-2.74l9.13-11.19l10.12-6.71l-5.18,8.7l5.68,0.75l9.63-4.23l1.73,6.96l6.66,1.49l6.91,6.71l0.49,4.97l-0.99,1.24l1.23,4.72h1.73l0.25-7.96h1.97l0.49,19.64l4.94-4.23l-3.46-20.39h-5.18l-5.68-7.21l27.89-47.25l-27.64-21.63l-30.85,5.97l-1.23,9.45l6.66,3.98l-2.47,6.47L93.11,44.89L93.11,44.89M148.76,158.34l-1,4.02l-3.49-2.26h-1.74l-1,4.27l-12.21,27.36l3.24,23.84l3.99,2.01l0.75,6.53h8.22l7.97,6.02l15.69,1.51l1.74,8.03l2.49,1.76l3.49-3.51l2.74,1.25l2.49,11.54l4.23,2.76l3.49-6.53l10.71-7.78l6.97,3.26l5.98,0.5l0.25-3.76l12.45,0.25l2.49,2.76l0.5,6.27l-1.49,3.51l1.74,6.02h3.74l3.74-5.77l-1.49-2.76l-1.49-6.02l2.24-6.78l10.21-8.78l7.72-2.26l-1-7.28l10.71-11.55l10.71-1.76L272.8,199l10.46-6.02v-8.03l-1-0.5l-3.74,1.25l-0.5,4.92l-12.43,0.15l-9.74,6.47l-15.29,5l-2.44-2.99l6.94-10.5l-3.43-3.27l-2.33-4.44l-4.83-3.88l-5.25-0.44l-9.92-6.77L148.76,158.34L148.76,158.34z","name":"United States of America"},"pr":{"path":"M271.05,281.06l-2.64-0.89l-2.12,1.33l1.06,1.24l3.61,0.53L271.05,281.06L271.05,281.06z","name":"Puerto Rico"},
```

The Puerto Rico object itself reads as:

```
"pr":{"path":"M271.05,281.06l-2.64-0.89l-2.12,1.33l1.06,1.24l3.61,0.53L271.05,281.06L271.05,281.06z","name":"Puerto Rico"},
```

Yahoo!